# Increment date variable

Tags: date, sas, increment

I have a SAS dataset, in which I must add a date variable, starting with a certain date (ex: July 10, 2014). For each observation, the date must increase by one day. I cannot figure out how to increment the date. Whenever I try, I get the same date for all observations.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Why not edit it?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Let's assume your dataset looks as so:

**Have**

```
Obs Var1
1   Mazda
2   Ford
3   BMW
```

**Want**

```
Obs Date        Var1
1   01JAN2015   Mazda
2   02JAN2015   Ford
3   03JAN2015   BMW
```

You can use a [Sum Statement](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000780334.htm) with a [SAS Date Literal](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000289454.htm) to accomplish this goal.

```
data want;
    format Date date9. /* Makes date the first var, looks prettier */
    set have;
    if(_N_ = 1) then Date = '31DEC2014'd; /* Set initial value */
    Date+1; /* Increment SAS date value by 1 day for each day */
run;
```

If you have not used the automatic variable *N* before, it's an iteration counter for each time SAS goes from the top of the data step to the bottom.

The likely reason that you are seeing the same date for each day is because you are not retaining the value you want to increment. Consider the below example program:

```
data WontWork;
    set have;

    Add_Me = 1;

    /* Do loop just simulates dataset iterations */
    do i = 1 to 10;          
       Add_Me = Add_Me + 1;
       output;
    end;

drop i;
run;
```

**Explanation**

Whenever SAS runs through one iteration of the data step, the Program Data Vector (PDV) resets all non-automatic variables to missing. To fix this, you must either use a Retain statement and then increment the variable, or use a Sum Statement to do the job of both retaining and summing up the variable. The Retain/Sum Statements both tell SAS to remember the last value of a variable so that it does not get reset to missing when it iterates through the data step.  One unique property of the retain statement is that you can set an initial value. By default, the retain statement will initialize the variable as missing. The sum statement will always initialize a variable as missing.

```
data works;
   retain Add_Me 0;

   /* Do loop just simulates dataset iterations */
   do i = 1 to 10;
       Add_Me = sum(Add_Me, 1);
       output;
   end;

drop i;
run;
```

OR

```
data works2;

  /* Do loop just simulates dataset iterations */
  do i = 1 to 10;
      Add_Me+1;
      output;
  end;

drop i;
run;
```

Note that the sum statement does both of these steps, and also handles missing values.  Think of it as a shortcut.

I hope this resolved your problem, and again welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I couldn't think of that, I even used _n_ in the variable before Date.. Silly me